# Setting up Azure Ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

Essentially, I want to do everything that Active Directory does but with Azure. I want to implement Azure AD in a company, divide user roles, and create security and access policies. An example would be not allowing access to configurations or websites like YouTube. I have tried various methods, but I can't find a solution for what I'm looking for.

I tried using Conditional Access, but this feature only applies to web applications, and I need it for the entire environment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD is not an Active Directory Domain Controller.

To achieve your goal you need a combination of other Microsoft services like endpoint manager (intune) to administrate the security configurations of your endpoints, Microsoft defender for endpoints to apply the web filtering, dynamic/security groups to asing roles to your users, if you requiere to make an LDAP authentication or another active directory authentication you will requiere an Azure Active Directory Domain Service(this is not exactly and AD DC)

Hope this helps!